# How do Abstract classes help prevent reentrancy for multiple accounts?

Tags: solidity, evm, openzeppelin-contracts

I was reading through the openZeppelin contracts and saw the ReentrancyGuard contract, and realized I don't know how the EVM deals with these contracts.

Assuming you have a class:

```
contract someClass is ReentrancyGuard{

   function giveMeMyEther() external nonReentrant{
       //transfer ether from contract to sender;
   }
}
```

What's happening with the `nonReentrant` modifier?  It looks like multiple users would be overwriting each other's reentrancy locks all the time.

What I would *expect* is that it would modify the _status on `someClass`, which would (in effect) be a global lock on the contract.  I would expect to need something more like `mapping(address=>uint256)` to track reentrancy per user.

Based upon its widespread use, I assume that I don't understand what's going on in the EVM.

Here's the code for the current reentrancy guard modifier for openZeppelin:

```
abstract contract ReentrancyGuard {
uint256 private constant _NOT_ENTERED = 1;
uint256 private constant _ENTERED = 2;

uint256 private _status;

constructor() {
    _status = _NOT_ENTERED;
}
modifier nonReentrant() {
    require(_status != _ENTERED, "ReentrancyGuard: reentrant call");
    _status = _ENTERED;
    _;
    _status = _NOT_ENTERED;
}
```

Questions:

1. How is status not overridden when multiple users call the function?
2. How does the value of the _status persist between calls?
3. Is there something else that the EVM is doing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EVM is a single-threaded Turing Machine, no other user can capture it before the current contract's code is done executing (or is aborted).

Comment: It looks like there's something called a fallback function which is called whenever a contract receives ether.  Then this function is used to make a reentrant call back into the function.  So, the _status persists between calls because the original function is still running (albeit lower on the stack).  Combined with your answer about the EVM being single-threaded, it's starting to make sense.